# Merge [facebook-page] & [facebook-fanpage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

The descriptions of [facebook-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-page) & [facebook-fanpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-fanpage) are pretty much identical. Will you consider merging them?

Comment: The synonym is already proposed, but not that many people can vote on it.

Comment: Title suggestion - *Not a fan of [facebook-fanpage]? Try [facebook-page] instead!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[facebook-fanpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-fanpage) is now a syn. of [facebook-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-page). The operational differences (in terms of asking on SO) don't appear to be different from whether it's a fan page, a business page, a charity page, or a "name whatever you want" page.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough reputation, please vote here:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-page/synonyms